# Automatically and uniquely assign unused controller to dynamic amounts of players in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, local, multiplayer

I'm making a local multiplayer game with three gamepads and one keyboard controller. When I start the game, I want each instance of the same prefab to have a different controller assigned to it, because right now, I'm using the Player Input Manager to spawn new players when a key is pressed on the controller. This can identify each unique controller, but every player can be controlled by every controller.

I tried getting each new player's device ids, but I could not assign a controller to them, because the documentation for assigning/pairing controllers to gameOjbects is quite confusing to me.

What is the solution?